# Javascript preformatted text with cross-browser line breaks

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, line-breaks, pre, textnode

I have preformatted strings with line-breaks and multi-spaces and I want to append them into a text node.

```
<pre id="bar"></pre>

<script>
   var string = "Preformatted"
                + "\n"  // \r, \r\n, \n\r or what else?
                + "multispace     string";
   var text = document.createTextNode(string);
   document.getElementById('bar').appendChild(text);
</script>
```

I tried to adopt as line breaker:

- `\n` breaks lines in all browsers, but in IE (I'm testing on 7) becomes a space
- `\r` breaks lines only in IE
- `\r\n` works in all browser but in IE the space at beginning of second line is horror
- `\n\r` also ok in all, but in IE the space at the end of first line is inacceptable for my layout.

I can't use `<br>` and innerHTML because IE collapses multi-spaces.
jQuery `.text(string)` has exactly the same behavior of `.appendChild(createTextNode(string))`

How can I insert cross-browser line breaks?
Eventually, how can I easily detect if a browser supports `\n` or `\r` ?

Comment: You don't seem to be using jQuery, and I'm not even sure if this is what you're looking for, but you could use `if ($.browser.msie) { /* handle the \n here */}` and the rest normally, but you'd have to use jQuery or go to jQuery source and get the implementation of `$.browser.msie` and apply the same check and handle it differently than other browsers.

Comment: **Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/RMeML/1/

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe: I can use jQuery if there are no javascript solutions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seemed to work in all browsers I tested (safari, opera, chrome, firefox, ie7, ie8, ie9):

http://jsfiddle.net/4bQ5Q/1/

Code:

```
var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
textarea.value = "\n";
var eol = textarea.value.replace(/\r\n/, "\r");

var string = "Preformatted" + eol + "multispace     string";

var text = document.createTextNode(string);
document.getElementById('bar').appendChild(text);​
```

Comment: I'd rename that variable to `EOL`, make it global and use an IIFE to compute its value: http://jsfiddle.net/XsLME/

Comment: I'm fine with my comment `:)`

Comment: This solution is exactly what I dreamed. Thank you Esailija and Šime!

Answer (score 4):

Since IE seems to be odd one out, perhaps store the characters in a variable and use [conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512.aspx) to change it as necessary:

```
<script> var $LF = '\n'; </script>
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <script> $LF = '\r'; </script>
<![endif]-->

<script>
  var string = "Preformatted"
               + $LF
               + "multispace     string";
  var text = document.createTextNode(string);
  document.getElementById('bar').appendChild(text);
</script>
```

Your snippet does seem to display properly in at least IE8, thus the `lt IE 8` condition.

Comment: Thank you for IE test. 
But I think the point isn't to detect if IE or not, but if the browser (regardless which is) correctly displays `\r` or `\n`.

Answer (score 2):

In the meanwhile I found an easier solution that seems to be cross-browser:
`innerHTML` with a brute `<pre>` imposition

```
<div id="bar"></div>

<script>
  var string = "Preformatted \n"
             + "string \r"
             + "with \r\n"
             + "assorted \n\r"
             + "line   breaks";
  document.getElementById('bar').innerHTML = "<pre>"+string+"</pre>";
</script>
```

`\r\n` becomes a single return
`\n\r` double return

Imperfection: IE 10 compatibility mode 7 add a space at the end of final line.